# Construct Strings with UTF-8 characters from data

Tags: serial, string, data-type, print, char

I am printing some ASCII art to the Serial monitor from Arduino UNO, with some success. However, using string literals uses more memory than I would like. I wanted to try constructing the strings/chars from other data types so that I can manipulate the data and print the ascii art without storing it in string literals.

However, I have found that there seems to be no way to print UTF-8 characters other than from a string literal. Is this the case? Is there no way to construct a string containing characters that have numeric values that are too big for `char`?

As an example, to print "▓" works fine as a String literal but, it seams, no other way.

```
Serial.println("▓");                         // works fine  
Serial.println('▓');                         // char can't store value
Serial.println(String('▓'));                 // char can't store value
Serial.println(0x2593);                      // just prints the numeric value
Serial.println((char)0x2593);                // char can't store value
Serial.println((wchar_t)0x2593);             // doesn't work
Serial.println(String(0x2593));              // doesn't work
Serial.println(String((wchar_t)0x2593));     // doesn't work
```

Similarily with write() instead of print():

```
Serial.write("▓");                  // Works fine
Serial.write('▓');                  // char can't store value
Serial.write(0x2593);               // just prints the numeric value
Serial.write((char)0x2593);         // char can't store value
Serial.write((wchar_t)0x2593);      // doesn't work
```

I also tried deriving new component strings from a string literal using `substring()` and `charAt()`. Neither works. Both produce � in the output.

`String((char)65)` constructs the string "A" from the numeric value 65. Neither `String((char)0x2593)` nor `String((wchar_t)0x2593)` produce the desired results. Is there a way to construct a string from numeric values that are too big to store in 'char'?

Comment: try `Serial.println("\u2593");`

Comment: I would try printing  byte arrays that contain the UTF-8 serialisation, not the numeric code point.  For example \xe2 ,\x96, \x93 instead of \u2593

Answer (score 3):

As you have noticed, `Serial` doesn't know how to deal with `wchar_t`.
If you are building your strings algorithmically from Unicode code
points, you need to convert those code points to UTF-8 for printing. I
am not aware of any built-in function that does that. You may want to
search the library manager for a library providing this functionality.

Alternatively, you could write the conversion yourself: it is not that
complicated. For example, here is a function that converts any code
point from the BMP (i.e. < 2<sup>16</sup>) to an UTF-8 string:

```cpp
// A BMP multi-byte character, with terminating NUL byte.
struct Mbchar {
    char utf8[4];
};

// Convert a wide character to UTF-8. Only works within the BMP.
Mbchar wchar_to_utf8(wchar_t c) {
    Mbchar result;
    if (c < 128) {               // 0xxx.xxxx
        result.utf8[0] = c;
        result.utf8[1] = 0;
    } else if (c < 2048) {       // 110x.xxxx 10xx.xxxx
        result.utf8[0] = 0xc0 | (c >> 6);
        result.utf8[1] = 0x80 | (c & 0x3f);
        result.utf8[2] = 0;
    } else {                     // 1110.xxxx 10xx.xxxx 10xx.xxxx
        result.utf8[0] = 0xe0 | (c >> 12);
        result.utf8[1] = 0x80 | (c >> 6 & 0x3f);
        result.utf8[2] = 0x80 | (c & 0x3f);
        result.utf8[3] = 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Keep in mind that, depending on the Arduino you are using, `wchar_t` may
not support characters outside the BMP. The AVR-based Arduinos
definitively don't.

This function can be used like this:

```cpp
Serial.println(wchar_to_utf8(0x2593).utf8);  // prints “▓”
```

Comment: Might be worth adding that their `'▓'` usage will not produce a `wchar_t` type, it'll just produce some useless `char` value. They'd need `L'▓'` which they should be able to use in conjunction with your code in `Serial.println(wchar_to_utf8(L'▓').utf8);`